# Appending a string adds first line twice

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, string

I´m generating a list of product orders, which then is sent by mail to an employee.
The mail body (html) contains a formatted string of quantity and article number.
The string is generated like this:

```
                if (order.AssemblyOrderID == assemblyOrderIDs[assemblyOrderIDs.Count - 1])
                {
                    orderBody += order.OrderQuantity + "x " + order.Article.Article_Number + "<br />";

                    objMM.Body += orderBody;
                }
```

Problem:
The first line of this string is generated twice.
I stepped through my code but according to the debugger it is working as expected.

The mail instead shows a string like this:

2x 12345
 
2x 12345
9x 99999

Any suggestions?

Comment: maybe your problem is not in a code of composing a line, but code of constructing, or sending email. how about adding descriptions on your email codes.

Answer (score 3):

The mail body becomes double appended:

```
// lets assume both orderBody and mail body is empty here.
orderBody += ....; // Here order body becomes 2x 12345<br/>
objMM.Body += orderBody; // here objMM.body becomes 2x 12345
```

And at the next turn you again append it to the `orderBody` and the `orderBody` to the mail body again:

```
orderBody += ....; // Here order body becomes "2x 12345<br/>2x 99999<br/>"
objMM.Body += orderBody; // here objMM.body is "2x 12345<br/>" already and
// it becomes "2x 12345<br/>" + "2x 12345<br/>2x 99999<br/>"
```

Do not double append. Either assign `objMM.Body` outside the loop, or do this:

```
            if (order.AssemblyOrderID == assemblyOrderIDs[assemblyOrderIDs.Count - 1])
            {
                orderBody += order.OrderQuantity + "x " + order.Article.Article_Number + "<br />";
                objMM.Body = orderBody;
            }
```

Comment: Too early for me to figure that out by myself... Thank you!